# problems with requests in python list

Tags: python, python-3.x, request, python-requests

I am going to post `phone` in the app but I am getting error again and again. Because the structure of the post looks like that

```
data = {
         'login': 'login',
         'password': 'password',
         'data': '[{"user_id": "user_id","text": "key"}]'
       }

response = requests.post('url', data=data)
```

the problem with this code is that `user_id` and `key` because they are not default values they can be different. if I remove apostrophe from the list. Error occurs `Array is not Json`. If I put this like that

```
data = [
         {
           'login': 'login',
           'password': 'password',
           'data': {"user_id": user_id, "text": key}
         }
       ]
headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Accept': 'application/json'}
response = requests.post('url', json=data, headers=headers)
```

It throws another error `Login or Password is null`. How can I solve this problems any help plz? thank you in advance!

Comment: I think in json generally only double quotes are allowed.

Comment: `data` isn't JSON; it's a Python `dict`. `requests` will automatically encode a value passed via the `json` keyword argument.

Comment: Why did you make `data` a `list` in the second example, when it was a `dict` in the first?

Comment: And why did you make the `'data'` value a `dict` instead of a `list`?

Comment: @chepner Raises some great questions. Can you clarify things?

Comment: @chepner honestly speaking I am using requests for the first time. I have never used before. Please can you specify your aswer in more detail? A bit difficult to understand your comment!

Comment: @Nerd Which part/one of his comments?

Comment: 3rd and 4th comments of @chepner

Comment: They're quite similar. He's just asking why in your first code snippet, `data` is a `list`, whereas in the second, `data` is a `dict`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, you want to replace the hard-coded user id and key with values from a pair of variables. This shouldn't require any change in the *structure* of the payload. Just try

```
import json

user_id = "..."
key = "..."

request_data = [{"user_id": user_id, "text": key}]

data = {
     'login': 'login',
     'password': 'password',
     'data': json.dump(request_data)
   }

response = requests.post('url', data=data)
```

Comment: thanks for the answer now I have a new error with your solution `[{\"error\":1,\"text\":\"Array is invalid\",\"error_no\":201}]`

Comment: Sorry, forgot to make `request_data` a `list` instead of a `dict`.